# Is a quantum circuit with a controlled-T gate possible?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, quantum-circuit

This diagram comes from the textbook, Quantum information (Author: Stephen Barnett), fig. 6.13.

The problem is what I know that T gate isn't a multi-qubit gate, so is it possible that T gate becomes controlled-something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Any quantum gate has controlled variants that act on the same number of qubits as the original gate + a number of control qubits (1 or more).
In this case, the controlled T gate with a single control qubit is a 2-qubit gate with the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\pi/4} \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & T \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer and matrix form! I have been confused about how to understand it before your reply